# Need help in conditional join

Tags: join

There are two tables:

1. EMP (EName, Loc_ID)
2. Location (Loc_ID, Loc)

**Table: EMP**

```
EName      Loc_ID

 John         T
 Ron          H
 Seth         D
 {NULL}       I
```

**Table: Location**

```
Loc_ID        Loc

T           Tokyo
H           Houston
D           Dallas
I           Irving
```

**Question:** If Ename is not NULL: Select Ename, and Loc_ID. 
              If Ename is     NULL, Select Ename, and Loc

**Expected Output:**

```
EName      New_Loc

 John         T
 Ron          H
 Seth         D
 {NULL}       Irving
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query assumes that both Loc_ID and Loc are varchar fields (I think this is the only way this will work):

```
(SELECT e.EName, l.Loc_ID as New_Loc FROM EMP AS e 
 JOIN loc AS l ON e.Loc_ID = l.Loc_ID 
  WHERE e.EName IS NOT NULL) UNION 
(SELECT e.EName, l.Loc AS New_Loc FROM EMP AS e 
JOIN loc as l ON e.Loc_ID = l.Loc_ID 
WHERE e.EName IS NULL) ORDER BY EName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, there is the IF function:

```
SELECT EName, IF(EName, EName, Loc) AS New_Loc
```

I'm sure there are equivalents in other SQL implementations.

Comment: In most other SQL dialects this is called the COALESCE function.